# Почему не работает вызов функции переданной через props?

Tags: javascript, reactjs

В родительском компоненте есть такая функция

```
this.mobileMenuOpen = () => {

    console.log('тут')

    this.setState({
        mobileMenuShow: !this.state.mobileMenuShow,
    })

    console.log(this.state.mobileMenuShow)
}
```

Также внутри родительского компонента есть вот такой дочерний:

```
<BackgroundWave 
    link={this.waveBackground} 
    link2={this.waveBackgroundWrapper}
    onMobileMenuOpen={this.mobileMenuOpen}
    mobileMenuOpen={this.state.mobileMenuShow}
/>
```

В дочерний компонент передается функция выше `onMobileMenuOpen={this.mobileMenuOpen}`

Далее эта функция вызывается в дочернем компоненте:

```
function BackgroundWave(props) {

    let classBackground, classArrow = '';
    if(props.mobileMenuOpen) {
        classBackground = 'background-wave background-wave--opened';

    } else {
        classBackground = 'background-wave';
    }




    return (
        <div className={classBackground} ref={props.link2}>
            <canvas ref={props.link} id='background-animation' className='background-wave__item'></canvas>
            <div className='background-wave__opener-wrap' onClick={props.onMobileMenuOpen}>
                <svg className='background-wave__opener'>
                    <use xlinkHref='img/icons/sprite.svg#mobile-opener' />
                </svg>
            </div>
        </div>
    );

  }
```

Но вызов не срабатывает, я не могу понять почему, пробовал вызывать различными способами.

```
onClick={props.onMobileMenuOpen()}
onClick={() => {props.onMobileMenuOpen}}
```

Но это не помогло

Answer (score 0):

тут по коду есть несколько замечаний
так как onMobileMenuOpen - это функция, то

```
onClick={props.onMobileMenuOpen()}
onClick={() => {props.onMobileMenuOpen}}
```

не будет работать так как. в первом случае она отрабатывает на момент рендера а не клика, должно быть:
 `onClick={props.onMobileMenuOpen}`;
во втором случае при клике  у нас вообще ничего не просиходит. должно быть: `onClick={() => {props.onMobileMenuOpen()}}`

далее:

```
this.mobileMenuOpen = () => {

    console.log('тут')

    this.setState({
        mobileMenuShow: !this.state.mobileMenuShow,
    })

    console.log(this.state.mobileMenuShow)
}
```

может не работать так как методы класса определяются без `this` ->

```
class Example extends Component{
mobileMenuOpen = () => {}
  render(){}
}
```

вообще  вид  пропсы лучше выносить через деструкторы:

```
function BackgroundWave({link,mobileMenuOpen,link2,onMobileMenuOpen}) {
    let classBackground, classArrow = '';
    if( mobileMenuOpen) {
        classBackground = 'background-wave background-wave--opened';
    } else {
        classBackground = 'background-wave';
    }
    return (
        <div className={classBackground} ref={link2}>
            <canvas ref={link} id='background-animation' className='background-wave__item' />
            <div className='background-wave__opener-wrap' onClick={onMobileMenuOpen}>
                <svg className='background-wave__opener'>
                    <use xlinkHref='img/icons/sprite.svg#mobile-opener' />
                </svg>
            </div>
        </div>
    );
  }
```